# Izpack installer support for 64 bit machines

Tags: izpack

I am using Izpack for packaging my java application in the form of an installer. now i want to include 64 bit support for my application installer. My idea is to package both 32 and 64 bit java and mysql client for my installer and while installing ,our application installer should install 64 or 32  bit mysql/java  depending up on the architecture of the server.

Could anyone help me do this? I was thinking of making a dropdownbox with values 32bit and 64 bit and depending on this value unpack the necessary files. but this seems to be crude. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the $SYSTEM_ variables to access the JAVA variables and grab the architecture from that.

$SYSTEM_os_arch will give you the architecture of the jre but not the machine. If that would work for you I would then make a condition from the os arch and install the correct supporting apps based on the conditions.